# Switch a differential I²C bus section, controlled via I²C

Tags: switches, i2c, multiplexer, gpio

I want to separate a section of an I²C bus, controlled via an I²C message. (Similar to an I²C bus switch/multiplexer like e.g. PCA9540.)

Indeed the I²C bus to switch isn't a plain vanilla I²C bus, but rather a **4 wire differential** bus. I wanted to save myself from converting to and from plain I²C before and after a PCA9540, so I got the idea to use a quad SPDT (rather a 4PDT) to select between connection and separation (with termination) (e.g. (74)CBT3257).

Problem: Usual I²C-IO devices update their IOs during the acknowledge phase, but **not after stop condition.** So controlling the 4PDT by any of them leads to bus separation while SDA and SCL are both low, ending up in a race condition of both now separated I²C lines pulled up simultaneously.

Does anybody know of an I²C-IO with IO-update delayed until stop condition?
Is there a simple possibility to use a I²C multiplexer (which usually are delayed until stop condition, of course) to control the 4PDT?
Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't know if I'm the only one, but I don't understand *exactly* what you mean by: "*Usual I²C-IOs update their IOs during the acknowledge phase*". I understand the Ack process, but not how "*update their IOs*" relates to that. And without understanding *that*, it's impossible to understand the rest of the question too. Can you add some further details e.g. wiring and timing diagrams, showing signals and data transfers where you can add further clarification and explanations? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson: Take a look e. g. at data sheet for PCA9536, as found under nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9536.pdf on page 9, Fig. 7: The transition to "data 1 valid" in the bottom time line takes place at the very moment the ack. is transmitted. Every I²C-GPIO I took a look on behaves similar. The moment the _data out from port_ changes is what I meant by "update their IOs".

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few differential buses and their characteristics define possible switching methods. What transceivers do you use?

Regardless of the above, I think you are fighting windmills here.

- Even though differential buses generally capable of faster speeds, in your case they are limited by original I2C speed. *Converting to I2C and back at the MUX does not introduce any delays*.
- You want to use I2C to control the switch. This is fine. But if your bus is not something I2C device can be connected to then you *have to convert it to I2C* anyway, so that your message would be understood. And if you already converted it, why not convert MUX outputs again?
- Most of the analog switches have tri-stated outputs. So they can only be used with differential buses that support biasing, to avoid erroneous signals on disconnected segments. This is something that pure I2C MUX does for you automatically.

There are 2 and 8 channel switches like [TCA954*A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9546a.pdf) series, that are electrically capable of switching some of the differential buses. The problem is that their own I2C inputs internally connected to same wires.

There are I2C controlled analog switches, like [ADG715](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG714_715.pdf), [MAX4572](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4571-MAX4574.pdf), and some even designed for *differential signals*, like [LTC1393](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/138093f.pdf). Once again, you still have to convert differential to I2C in order to control that switch.

When I look at possible SDA/SCL combinations and transitions, I don't see anything that might affect either disconnected or new bus segment. The only exception is that old bus segment might miss stop condition. However, since *last command on that bus was addressed to the switch itself*, it doesn't really matter. The new bus segment might receive start condition and ACK as first bit, but it will be followed by stop condition anyway, so no problem here as well.

*But you have to figure out first if that is what you really need.* Otherwise you might end up with much more cumbersome schematics than simple translation to I2C and back at the MUX.

UPDATE

Here is final analog switch solution: Use either [MAX4562](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4562-MAX4563.pdf) on SDA line only or [MAX4572](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4571-MAX4574.pdf) on both SDA and SCL. Your differential segments connected to outputs must be [failsafe biased](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt514/slyt514.pdf) to ensure they translated into idle I2C state when segment disconnected from bus.

UPDATE 2

Since you are using dI2C it already requires termination with biasing, so a good fit for analog switch, which can be used to disconnect SDA or SCL or both. As I mentioned above, this will create several racing situations resulting in slaves on disconnected segment receiving either string of start-stop conditions or continuous stream of "1" bits. While neither of these should result in unexpected actions by slaves, it is not a clean design.

So, I am standing behind my initial assessment that using normal I2C switch and two differential transceivers before and after it would be most robust solution.

Comment: Of course, differential signalisation isn't any faster, but it's less prone to electrical disturbances.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of the I²C controlled analog switches. Indeed, the LTC1393's action is delayed until stop condition, but due to it's DP4T nature, two would be needed – so converting plain I²C back to differential I²C would be the better solution, notably if price comes to mention. (Btw., forgot to mention, conversion is done by PCA9614).

Comment: Regarding disconnecting the low-stated bus: If the disconnected bus receives a start condition during disconnection, a slave might lock the SDA line, preventing generating stop. Albeit, you are right, this should not happen, because in the eyes of the disconnected bus this would look like the beginning of addressing phase, when no data should be output on SDA. Also there is only a single master and no SCL-driving slaves.

Comment: The use of PCA9614 is good fit for analog switches as dI2C requires biasing resistors anyway. Note that you cannot use LTC1393, because it is unidirectional. That is why I suggested either MAX4562/MAX4572 analog switch or PCA9540 with conversion back to I2C. If analog switch only triggers during ACK (C=H, D=L) then disconnected bus will see D->H (due to biasing) which is stop condition. If it happens before ACK (C=L, D=L) then disconnected bus _will_ miss stop if only SDA switched and _might_ miss stop if both switched.

Comment: The LTC1393 could be used to generate control signals for a level controlled ("plain") analog switch. As far as I undstood e.g. PCA9536's functionality, it triggers updating its IOs _after_ ack. i.e. in that moment when SCL becomes L.

Answer (score 0):

The hints and answers so far let me conclude, that indeed treating a second PCA9614 to it in order to convert from and to differential I²C is the simplest approach.

Another idea is to use SDA as clock for a D-FF that captures state of SCL when SDA becomes H and hence generates a rising edge on stop condition. It triggers a second D-FF that delays the output of a GPIO device until stop condition. Maybe this gives minimal cost benefit, but a ic count drawback, and, as slew rate constraints will be presumably hardly met, seems to be a little bit hackerish.

Comment: Caution: Due to the usual 0.5 V threshold of bidirectional drivers (that helps to distinguish the driver's own low from any other's low and that also applies to the PCA9614), the simple concatenation of two PCA9614 back-to-back (or rather belly-to-belly) does not work. The low from the mutual PCA9614 is treated the same way as the own low: It isn't propagated to the differential side. The switch in between them doesn't affect this behaviour.

Comment: Finally, I successfully used the D-FF-delay method.

The slow rising edge that triggers the FF seems to be of no problem, as the exact moment of triggering doesn't matter, as well as potential multiple triggering doesn't harm.